# Mac版AtomでPDFが自動で開かない

Tags: macos, atom-editor, latex

MacTeXを導入し、Atomで `command + s` や `control + alt + b` を入力しましたが、PDFが表示されないです。
しかし、PDFファイルは保存されています。
下の画像のように保存やコンパイルをしたら自動で右のタブに表示されるようにしたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Atomのバージョンは 1.60.0 x64 です。
どなたか教えてくださると幸いです。

以下、テストファイルのソースとMacTeXの導入手順です。

#### ソース

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}
\begin{document}

\title{テスト}
\author{数学・統計学探訪}
\maketitle

\section{テスト}
これはテストです。

\begin{equation}
  x+y+5=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

#### 導入手順

- `brew install mactex --cask` でMacTeXを導入。
- `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` を入力。
- `sudo tlmgr paper a4` でデフォルトの用紙サイズをA4に設定。
- atom内で、拡張機能である latex, latexer, language-latex, pdf-view を導入。
- 拡張機能のlatexの設定で、Engineの項目を `default` から `uplatex` に変更。
- また、`Build on save` にチェックを入れ、`Open Result after Sccesful Build` と `Open Result in Buckground` のチェックを外した。

Comment: 拡張機能 latex の設定のところですが PDF Producer は `dvipdfmx` に設定されていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
確認したところ、確かに```dvipdfmx```に設定されておりました。

Comment: 質問が解決済みかどうかは、(回答が付いた後に) [あなたが回答を承認することでマークが付与されます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 。 / 目立たせることだけを目的とするようなタイトルの編集は避けてください。